# How to add padding/margin to all child component from parent View component in react native?

Tags: react-native

I want to add same padding/margin to all of my child component(`Icon`) just putting style in `View` component. How can I achieve?

```js
<View style={{flexDirection: "row",}}>
    <Icon name={'star'} color={Gold} size={14}/>
    <Icon name={'star'} color={Gold} size={14}/>
    <Icon name={'star'} color={Gold} size={14}/>
    <Icon name={'star'} color={Gold} size={14}/>
</View>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is actually possible for the parent to modify its children. Take a look at the following wrapper component:

```
const Wrapper = ({ childStyle, children, ...viewProps }) => (
  <View {...viewProps}>
    {React.Children.map((children, child) =>
      React.cloneElement(child, {
        style: [child.props.style, childStyle],
      }),
    )}
  </View>
);

// This will add margin to all your stars:
<Wrapper style={{flexDirection: "row",}} childStyle={{margin: 8}}>
    <Icon name={'star'} color={Gold} size={14}/>
    <Icon name={'star'} color={Gold} size={14}/>
    <Icon name={'star'} color={Gold} size={14}/>
    <Icon name={'star'} color={Gold} size={14}/>
</View>
```

This uses `React.Children.map` to iterate over the children the `Wrapper` is given, and then `React.cloneElement` to transform them and inject the styles we pass from the parent.

Answer (score 2):

For those trying Marek Lisik's answer, I believe there is a typo in his answer. His code did not work for me until I changed argument to React.Children.map to:

```
React.Children.map(children, (child) => { /* your code here /* })
```

Instead of:

```
React.Children.map((children, child) => {/* this does not work as children is already declared a prop */}
```

Unfortunately, I cannot comment on his answer since my reputation isn't high enough. Hopefully someone will find my measly answer worthy enough.

Answer (score 1):

Add a style prop to each Icon

```
<Icon name={'star'} color={Gold} size={14} style={{ margin: 10 }} />
```

**Edit:**
I don't think you can set a margin from parent component.
If you don't want to write the style prop 5 times you can make a custom icon component:

```
const CustomIcon = ({name, color, size}) => (
   <Icon name={name} color={color} size={size} style={{ margin: 10 }} />
)
```

And then call this component instead of Icon:

```
<CustomIcon name={'star'} color={Gold} size={14} />
```

Comment: Thanks. Now, I am using your approach. But I am looking for if there is any possible way to do in parent component. Because in this approach, I have to write it 5 times.

Comment: Thanks. But this approach will fail when I use different child components